# Getting an array value if there is a `?`

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have a variable of type `ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>?`, how can I get the first array element?

Context:

```cs
var test = playerInputActions.devices;
Debug.Log("test: " + test.GetValueOrDefault());
// Output: test: UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities.ReadOnlyArray`1[[UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputDevice, Unity.InputSystem, Version = 1.0.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null]]
```

Things that won't work:

```
test[0]
// Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>?

test.GetValueOrDefault()[0]
// ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
// Parameter name: index
```

Comment: Linq (or its extension methods ) is not working on Unity?

Comment: @Eldar Please can you elaborate?

Comment: adding `using System.Linq` and using it `test?.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: How would I log the result to the console, given the `?` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to [`ReadOnlyArray<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.1/api/UnityEngine.Experimental.Input.Utilities.ReadOnlyArray-1.html) which is a `struct`.

**The [implicit operator `?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.op_implicit) makes it a [`Nullable<ReadOnlyArray<T>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1).**

Writing

```
Nullable<ReadOnlyArray<T>> x;
```

and

```
ReadOnlyArray<T>? x;
```

basically is completely equivalent.

---

Little background: "Why would they use a nullable at all?"

-> Because value types can not be `null` but rather always have a value per default. So in order to show that the result is invalid you can either invent a special value/property within your struct which indicates whether the result is valid or not or you can use `Nullable<T>` which allows you to simply

```
return null;
```

in the case you want to indicate an invalid result.

---

What you want to do is accessing its [`Nullable<T>.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value#System_Nullable_1_Value) like e.g.

```
if(test.HasValue)
// Or also
//if(test != null)
{
    var device = test.Value[0];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake, you can also do this check with `test.HasValue`. :)

Comment: @Andrew I know .. do you know if it makes actually any difference in the background?

Comment: I'm not sure, I mentioned it just as an alternative. If `!=` calls `Equals`, we save a few nanoseconds, as `Equals` calls one or two `HasValue`. :D [Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,7cf83901b2b7e0f9,references). I'm not sure if with `!=` it casts `null` to `Nullable`, I did a quick search but couldn't find anything. I'd say it's a matter of preference, you may use `HasValue`if you want to make it clear that it's a `Nullable`.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for that source! Looks like `HasValue` is actually the better way since `Equals` internally uses it anyway ;) -> Updated

Comment: A new handy way is made available by pattern matching. `if (test is { Length: > 0 } a) { var result = a[0]; }`. This pattern does 3 things: 1. tests whether `test` is not null. 2. Tests whether the array has at least one element. 3. If both tests succeed, `test.Value` is assigned to the new variable `a`, which is of the not nullable type `ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yeah well ... personally I would not use it though .. I assume the performance is the same and writing it out is just (in my personal opinion) way better to read and understand for someone else looking into my code ^^ But anyway, always open to learn something new so thanks for sharing! By `new` you mean in c#8 or c#9 ? (Depends on the used Unity version whether it supports it already e.g. [2021.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html) or [2020.3 LTS](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html) etc )

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for this very insightful answer!